# How long do Wookiees live?

Tags: star-wars

Within the *Star Wars* timeline, we first see Chewbacca in *Episode III: The Revenge of the Sith*. In it he appears as a full grown adult and seems to have a high status within his community. Then, of course, he appears in the "middle 3" episodes, where he pretty much looks the same.  Now he has appeared in *Episode VII: The Force Awakens*, still looking as if he hasn't aged. That is a period of over 50 years. How long do Wookiees live, and how do they change as they age?

Canon answers preferred, if possible.

Comment: Hmm ... did a search for this before asking and didn't find anything, nor did I see a duplicate in the "helpful" box of similar questions that popped up as I was typing this.